# Is this tensor contraction correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

If I start off with the $\left(p,q\right)$-tensor given by $$T_{i_1,\dots,i_p}^{j_1,\dots,j_q}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_p}\otimes\varepsilon^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\varepsilon^{j_q}$$ and I contract the last indices, then do I end up with $$T_{i_1,\dots,i_{p-1},k}^{j_1,\dots,j_{q-1},k}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{p-1}}\otimes\varepsilon^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\varepsilon^{j_{q-1}}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form is
$T_{j_1,\dots,j_p}^{i_1,\dots,i_q}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_p}\otimes\varepsilon^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\varepsilon^{j_q}.$

After contraction,

$T_{j_1,\dots,j_{p-1}{\ }\ ,k}^{i_1,\dots,i_{q-1}{\ }\ ,k}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{p-1}}\otimes\varepsilon^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\varepsilon^{j_{q-1}}$

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Using_tensor_products) is a useful  reference.

Comment: This looks the same but with the indices on $T$ flipped.

Comment: Yes.  Any repeated index symbol is summed over. And one time the index is superscript and the other is subscript. @user333434

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good to know that I had the right idea.